# How to join 4 tables with specific requirements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum

I have 4 tables.

```
Procedures

Name   Cost
Proc1  10
Proc2  20
Proc3  30
Proc4  40

MaterialsUsed

NameOfTheProcedure  MaterialUsed  AmountOfMaterialUsed
proc1               mat1              1
proc2               mat2              3
proc3               mat3              2
proc4               mat4              1

Materials

Name   Id   Price
mat1   1    10
mat2   2    20
mat3   3    30
mat4   4    40

ProceduresDone

ClientID   NameOfProcedure  Date
Client1    proc1            2012-11-24
Client2    proc2            2012-11-23
Client3    proc3            2012-11-24
Client4    proc4            2012-11-23
```

I need to write a query which returns procedures done on the specific date. It should have 3 columns (NameOfTheProcedure, HowManyTimesThatProcedureWasDoneInThatDay, TotalPrice). The TotalPrice column includes both prices from materials table and from procedures one.

Is it possible to do that with a single query?

EDIT:

Sample result should look something like that (on date 2012-11-24) :

```
NameOfTheProcedure    AmountOfTimesProcedureWasDoneThatDay    TotalPrice
proc1                 1                                       20
proc3                 1                                       90
```

Comment: what rdbms you are using? sqlserver? mysql? oracle? etc..

Comment: can you specify sample result? what is i searched for `2012-11-24` what will be the result?

Comment: Added the sample result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this,

```
SELECT  a.NameOfTheProcedure,
        COUNT(a.NameOfTheProcedure) AmountOfTimesProcedureWasDoneThatDay,
        SUM(b.AmountOfMaterialUsed * d.Price) +
        SUM(c.Cost) TotalPrice
FROM    ProceduresDone a
        INNER JOIN MaterialsUsed b
            ON a.NameOfProcedure = b.NameOfTheProcedure
        INNER JOIN Procedures c
            ON c.Name = a.NameOfProcedure
        INNER JOIN Materials d
            ON b.MaterialUsed = d.Name
WHERE   a.Date = '2012-11-24'
```